# A complex mysql query to get date

Tags: php, mysql, join

i have four tables like:

```
- accounts
1. id
2. register_date
3. package
4. status

- company
1. id
2. brand
3. account_id

- packages
1. id
2. title
3. experience ( for example that package's time is 30 day, it will expire after that and related account's status will be 0)

Example scenario:

accounts
------------
id=>1
register_date=>2015-01-27 23:36:38
package=>1
status=>1

company
------------
id=>1
brand=>Burger King
account_id=>1

packages
------------
id=>1
title=>Economic Package
experience=>30
```

Now, i just want to lookup who's account will expire in 10 days.
In my little head i thought i will add package's expericence to account's register date and substract it from current time and check if its smaller or equals to 10. I need it in single query but my mysql knowledge is not big enough to solve this problem. Thanks for every answer...

Comment: you can't just add a random number to a date. e.g. what's `18 Mar 2015 + 30`? 38 Mar? 2048? that being said, you **CAN** do math on dates in mysql, e.g. `select * from yourtable WHERE register_date < now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY` would find all records where the register_date is 31days or older.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for ...

```
SELECT `accounts`.*
FROM `accounts`
    INNER JOIN `packages` ON `packages`.`id` = `accounts`.`package`
WHERE DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(`accounts`.`register_date`,INTERVAL `packages`.`experience` DAY) ,NOW()) = 10
```

Comment: thanks dude! i am going to try it, but i just want to get brand name from company :)

Answer (score -1):

Query are all your packages set at 30? Or are some of them smaller and already below 10, if that is so then you can just query for them through the packages time left being active.

Comment: this is a comment not an answer